# How do I get a list of craft provided events at runtime?

Tags: events

The documentation provides a very [comprehensive list of events](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference) provided by Craft  but I would like to know if there is a way to get a list of those events at runtime.

Having such list would enable me to display a `<select>` field whereby a user could choose the event that should trigger an action.

Think of it as **dynamic event registration!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events don’t get pre-registered anywhere in Craft, so there’s no way to easily fetch a definitive list of all events that will ever get called, but with a little PHP we can get a pretty good idea of what they all are.

You’d start by getting a list of all the components on [WebApp](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/web/WebApp) (what `craft()` returns) by calling its [getComponents()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModule#getComponents-detail) method, loop through each of them, use reflection to get each of their methods, and find the ones that start with `on`. (By convention, all event methods should start with that, and non-event methods generally shouldn’t start with that, although it’s possible this will yield some false positives, so make sure you double-check the results.)

```php
$events = [];
$components = craft()->getComponents(false);

foreach ($components as $id => $component)
{
    // Skip some non-existent components
    if ($id == 'fieldTypes' || $id == 'file')
    {
        continue;
    }

    // If the component hasn't been loaded yet, $component will just be its config array
    if (is_array($component))
    {
        $component = craft()->getComponent($id);
    }

    // Find the event methods
    $class = new \ReflectionClass($component);
    $methods = $class->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);

    foreach ($methods as $method)
    {
        if (strncasecmp($method->name, 'on', 2) === 0)
        {
            $events[] = $id.'.'.$method->name;
        }
    }
}

// Dump 'em out
Craft::dd($events);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks a bunch Brandon!

Comment: @SelvinOrtiz Just made a quick edit after testing locally - apparently we have a couple component definitions that shouldn't actually be there. I'll remove those for the next release, but for now you can just skip them with a quick conditional.